# I'm facing a problem with taking a Preview Video in iPhone Application

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to 2 ways to Record the Preview View for iPhone Application :

1. Using "xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo appVideo.mov" command written in a terminal. I take a 4 to 5 Video. But, no one video was smooth. In Simulator running fine. But, After recording, it's not smooth. It's stuck for 2 to 3 seconds
2. Press Shift-Command-5. But, Screen not resizable.

I checked Network speed is below :

**Downloading:** 95.45 Mbps

**Uploading:** 95.43 Mbps

I tried after restarting Simulator and Mac PC also. But no luck.
Does anyone guess what else could be causing this problem?